# Determining if dice are fair using statistics

Tags: statistics

A casino must demonstrate to the state gaming commission that every die it uses is fair. a machine is used to roll each die 1200 times. a die is discarded if the following assumption it is fair is rejected at the 10% significance level. determine if the following results suggest a die is accepted or rejected by the casino.

then it proceeds to show a picture of a die with the number 1 rolled 190 times, a die with the number 2 rolled 220 times and a die with the number 4 rolled 185 times.

Comment: welcome to stack exchange. what have you tried so far? knowing where your stuck will make it easier to help.

Comment: I've tried the chi-square test statistic, but it's still a little confusing.

Comment: Chi-square is a good approach, given the large number of tosses. What is confusing about applying this test?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are supposed to conclude that occurrences of faces 3. 5. and 6
together amounted to $1200 - 595 = 605$, but are given no information
on how many times each of these faces appeared.

In that case you can do a chi-squared goodness of fit test
with four categories: '1', '2', '4', and '356'. Their observed
counts are 190, 220, 185, and 605, and their expected counts
are 200, 200, 200, and 600, respectively. Then the chi-squared
goodness-of-fit statistic is $Q = 3.67.$ Under the null
hypothesis that the die is fair, $Q \stackrel{approx}{\sim} Chisq(df = 3).$

```
 X = c(190, 220, 185, 605)
 E = c(200, 200, 200, 600)
 Q = sum((X-E)^2/E);  Q
 ##  3.666667
```

Since you know something about such tests, and hoping that I
have cleared up whatever was confusing you about this problem,
I suppose you can take it from there to determine whether
to judge that the die is unfair. (The problem would have been
straightforward if you had been given observed frequencies
for all six faces of the die.)